# select the row with most recent date in table formed by using join and group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i am joining three tables and applying group by to pick a single distinct row of each type. when i join with table marketing_follow i have multiple entries and to pick one i am using group by . now i want to pick the entry with most recent date in follow up table . i've been tryn to get this done for quite some time now and really need some help

```
public function getRegionWiseUserDetails($array){

    $this->db->select('mg.region_name, mu.contact_person, mu.contact_number, mu.status, mu.company_name, mu.user_type, mf.follow_up_date, mf.date, mu.user_id');


   $this->db->from('marketing_users as mu');
    $this->db->join('marketing_group as mg','mg.id = mu.region_id','left');
    $this->db->join('marketing_follow_up as mf','mf.user_id_fk = 
    mu.user_id','left');
   foreach($array as $condition){
       $this->db->or_where('mg.id',$condition);
   }
   $this->db->order_by('mf.follow_up_date','asc');
   $this->db->group_by('mf.user_id_fk');


   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();
  }
```

Comment: `$this->db->order_by('mf.follow_up_date','desc');` try with this

Comment: Are you using data tables for showing all data?? Because it should work otherwise.

Comment: I can write the raw query, but you (or others) would have to figure out how to translate that to this framework. If that's a solution, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry :- that would really help. i'll try and translate it for codeignotor

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the date field in  `desc` order. Also for **asc** we dont have to pass it as second paramter it defaults accept **asc**

```
 $this->db->order_by('mf.follow_up_date','desc');
```